# Upgrade git version during Rebase

Tags: git

I've done a rebase of feature branch into development branch, and I'm about to push. I need to push with  `--force-with-lease` option, but git throws an error. I noticed that I have git version 1.8.3 installed, while this option was introduced in 1.8.5. Is there any risk of losing progress in my rebase process if I upgrade git version now to 2.16.6?

I'm working on Centos 7.

Comment: If you gonna push it's not "during rebase". You've already finished rebase.

Comment: It may seem crazy, but some people updgrade their software before it gets years out of date even before they're looking for a new feature.... just a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does sometimes change the rebase disk structures under the hood, although usually minor jumps are not a problem.  If you've already finished the rebase and are ready to push, then the rebase is done, any state has been erased, and upgrading isn't a problem.

If you're still in the middle of the rebase, I'd recommend holding off on your upgrade.  1.8.3 is quite old, and it's possible that Git has changed the way it's done things internally between then and 2.16.